# Hibernate, Multithreading and CascadeType.ALL

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

In a multithreaded environment,

**This works**

```
Box box = new Box("B");
Toy t1 = box.addNewToy("t1");
Toy t2 = box.addNewToy("t2");
synchronized (em) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(t1);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
synchronized (em) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(t2);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

**But this doesn't**

```
Box box = new Box("B");
Toy t1 = box.addNewToy("t1");
synchronized (em) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(t1);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
Toy t2 = box.addNewToy("t2");
synchronized (em) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(t2);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

I get errors like: "object references an unsaved transient instance", "a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session"

Any ideas?

Here is a minimal Maven project that reproduces the problem: http://www.2shared.com/file/bGLmJ6aO/example.html

**Details**

java version "1.7.0_17", hibernate 4.2.3.Final, Ubuntu 11.04 natty, SQLite

```
class Toy {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="toys",fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Box> getBoxes() { return boxes; }

    public void setBoxes(List<Box> boxes) { this.boxes = boxes; }
}

class Box {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Toy> getToys() { return toys; }

    public void setToys(List<Toy> toys) { this.toys = toys; }

    public Toy addNewToy(String name) {
        Toy toy = new Toy();
        toy.setName(name);
        toy.boxes.add(this);
        toys.add(toy);
        return toy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a typo in your first code block? There's no t2.

Answer (score 1):

> A EntityManagerFactory is an expensive-to-create, threadsafe object intended to be shared by all application threads. It is created once, usually on application startup.
>
> An EntityManager is an inexpensive, **non-threadsafe** object that should
>   be used once, for a single business process, a single unit of work,
>   and then discarded. ...

See: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/#transactions-basics

I'm not exactly sure what you're doing but if you're using that same static EntityManager from multiple threads then that's your problem.

The `EntityManagerFactory` is the thread-safe object you want to share, but you should create a new EntityManager for each request/unit of work being performed.

Comment: So this "synchronized" in front of save() doesn't really help? I'm using a single EntityManager across multiple threads but I encapsulate it inside an object that ensures that every access to it is atomic.

Comment: entityManagers should be created for each business case, thats what i think.